# AWS, ecs alarm metric, there are two memory utilization metric, difference?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

[image]

There's memory-utilization metric under both of

- ClusterName, ServiceName
- ClusterName

I can't tell the difference of the two..

Comment: If you have multiple services running within the same cluster the two metrics start to differ. If you only have one service they are identical.

Answer (score 0):

ClusterName
This dimension filters the data that you request for all resources in a specified cluster. All Amazon ECS metrics are filtered by ClusterName.

ServiceName
This dimension filters the data that you request for all resources in a specified service within a specified cluster.

Cluster metrics are scoped as ECS > ClusterName and service utilization metrics are scoped as ECS > Cluster